# How can I set the Data Label position for an Excel pie chart using C#?

Tags: c#, epplus

I am creating an Excel export that contains several pie charts which are dynamically created based on data from a database that is dumped into a range of cells within the spreadsheet.  I need the data labels for the pie charts to be on the outside end of the pie chart.  The data labels by default are set to best fit.

I have tried to manipulate the data label positions with `eLabelPosition` which has an `OutEnd` property but have had no luck.  Doing this causes the data labels to completely disappear.

Below is the method I am using to generate my pie charts.

```
    private void AddPieChart(ExcelWorksheet worksheet, int firstDataRow, int firstDataColumn, int lastDataRow, int nextColumn, int firstColumn)
    {
        ExcelPieChart pieChart = worksheet.Drawings.AddChart(worksheet.Name.ToString() + " Pie Chart", eChartType.Pie3D) as ExcelPieChart;
        var serie = pieChart.Series.Add(ExcelCellBase.GetAddress(firstDataRow + 3, firstDataColumn, lastDataRow + 3, firstDataColumn),
                                        ExcelCellBase.GetAddress(firstDataRow + 3, firstColumn, lastDataRow + 3, firstColumn));

        pieChart.DataLabel.ShowCategory = true;
        pieChart.DataLabel.ShowLeaderLines = true;
        pieChart.DataLabel.Font.Bold = true;
        pieChart.DataLabel.Font.Size = 12;
        pieChart.Legend.Remove();
        pieChart.SetSize(500, 350);
        pieChart.SetPosition(lastDataRow + 5, 0, nextColumn - 1, 0);
        pieChart.Border.Fill.Color = Color.White;
        pieChart.Series.Chart.RoundedCorners = false;

        var pieSerie = (ExcelPieChartSerie)serie;
        pieSerie.DataLabel.Position = eLabelPosition.OutEnd;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that if you have `DataLabel` properties assigned to your `ExcelPieChart` and then also attempt to assign the `DataLabel` properties on the `ExcelPieChartSerie` is does not apply the property to the `ExcelPieChartSerie`. In order to fix this remove any of the `DataLabel` properties on the `ExcelPieChart` and instead add them to the `ExcelPieChartSerie` as shown below.

```
private void AddPieChart(ExcelWorksheet worksheet, int firstDataRow, int firstDataColumn, int lastDataRow, int nextColumn, int firstColumn)
        {
            ExcelPieChart pieChart = worksheet.Drawings.AddChart(worksheet.Name.ToString() + " Pie Chart", eChartType.Pie3D) as ExcelPieChart;
            var serie = pieChart.Series.Add(ExcelCellBase.GetAddress(firstDataRow + 3, firstDataColumn, lastDataRow + 3, firstDataColumn),
                                            ExcelCellBase.GetAddress(firstDataRow + 3, firstColumn, lastDataRow + 3, firstColumn));
            pieChart.Legend.Remove();
            pieChart.SetSize(500, 350);
            pieChart.SetPosition(lastDataRow + 5, 0, nextColumn - 1, 0);
            pieChart.Border.Fill.Color = Color.White;
            pieChart.Series.Chart.RoundedCorners = false;

            var pieSerie = (ExcelPieChartSerie)serie;
            pieSerie.DataLabel.ShowCategory = true;
            pieSerie.DataLabel.ShowLeaderLines = true;
            pieSerie.DataLabel.Font.Bold = true;
            pieSerie.DataLabel.Font.Size = 12;
            pieSerie.DataLabel.Position = eLabelPosition.OutEnd;
        }
```